# VBScript sendkeys doesn't work on powershell in admin mode

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have a vbscript that spawns powershell in admin mode via:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")  
oShell.ShellExecute "powershell", "-executionpolicy bypass", "", "runas", 1
```

and then I attempt to send keys via:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.sleep 2000
WshShell.sendkeys "hello"
```

Since the keys didn't work, I tried separating the latter part into a separate file and specifically did a WshShell.AppActivate on the PID to make sure it gets the right window focus before sendkeys, however it still won't send the string.

Conversely, if I don't run powershell in admin, everything works fine:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run "powershell"
WScript.sleep 200
WshShell.sendkeys "cls"
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have an official reference for you, I'm pretty sure that *by design*, for security reasons, you can *not* send keystrokes to *elevated* (run-as-admin) processes from a *non*-elevated process.

If this were possible, non-elevated processes could *bypass* their limited privileges, which would be an obvious violation of the rules.